# Is there any way to get the iPhone Model number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I just figure out the device on which i'm working by the code given bellow:

```
struct utsname systemInfo;

uname(&systemInfo);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.version
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

But is there any way to find the model of my iPhone??? Thanks in advance ....

Comment: What do you need to know the model for? In most situations you'll want to check for the hardware you need, not the model. For example, you'll ask if there's a camera before trying to use it, you don't really care if it's an iPhone or an iPod touch.

Comment: because i have to call a web-service and there is a need of this model number..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the model of iPhone from code. (e.g. MC143C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979429/how-to-get-the-model-of-iphone-from-code-e-g-mc143c)

Answer (score 0):

the [`UIDevice` class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model) might help...  the following will get you  `@”iPhone”` or `@”iPod touch”` according to the docs, but to be more specific about `3G` or `3GS` you might need something trickier... what kind of model info do you need?

`NSString *s = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];`

Comment: tried already....

I can see the model number from my iPhone 3G which is "MC143C"...

i need to have that model number.

please help me if you can.

thanks for reply...