# Get iPhone color iOS Sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-privateapi

iTunes can detect if my iPhone is black or white, so how can I do this in code?

I'm thinking it would be a UIDevice thing but I'm not too sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Color of iPhone/iPad/iPod touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463212/detecting-color-of-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can obtain color from model part number, for example:

> MD381 - black iPhone 4S
>
> MC920 - white iPhone 4S
>
> ...

To obtain model number use  [**uidevice-extension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979429/how-to-get-the-model-of-iphone-from-code-e-g-mc143c)

**Addition**:
Alternative solution. Link your project with libLockdown.dylib.

```
extern id lockdown_connect();
extern id lockdown_copy_value(id, id, id);
extern void lockdown_disconnect();
extern NSString *kLockdownDeviceColorKey;
NSString* CopyDeviceColor() {
    id connection = lockdown_connect();
    NSString *color = lockdown_copy_value(connection, nil, kLockdownDeviceColorKey);
    NSLog(@"color = %@", color);
    lockdown_disconnect(connection);
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Hi dont seem to be able to get that code to run. I did add liblockdown.dylib to Xcode project. But I cant figure out how to #import it in .m file therefore each time I run it, it crushes. Im sure I am missing something obvious. Suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: @stringCode https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/liblockdown.h try this

Answer (score 2):

iTunes detects the color of the device from the serial number I believe.

There is no way to determine the color of the device or developers.

Comment: I don't think because, for example, all 5S have the same model numbers, and iTunes is still able to detect the color.