# How to get the device Model in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on an app which is having a functionality of showing details about device like "Device Name", "Version", "Model" and etc.  I'm able to get all the other things what I need but not able to get the "Model" in specific.  Currently i'm getting "iPad 3G" but I want it as MC705LL (iPad 3G).

Is there any possible way to get the above info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the model of iPhone from code. (e.g. MC143C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979429/how-to-get-the-model-of-iphone-from-code-e-g-mc143c)

Comment: Thank you Parag,  Now i'm getting Model Number as "MC705".  What is "LL" refers and I want that one also.  Is there any way to get it.