# How to fetch Model number in apple devices programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to fetch the Apple device model number using objective-c.
I do not want write below code.
[Hard code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN0aP.png) 
I want the model number like,
e.g Model A1432,
Model A1454,
Model A1455,
For more...
[Apple devices model list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC2oj.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want the model number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model

Comment: Ckeck [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296760/how-to-get-the-device-model-in-objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296760/how-to-get-the-device-model-in-objective-c)

Comment: Because I need to send model number for webservice request